# =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(SUBSTITUTE

Tags: excel, if-statement, search, excel-formula, substitution

I have two working formulas

1. `=SUBSTITUTE(J136,"SE Ext '22","OE 23")`

**This is being run in column C**

and

2. `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(K136,C136)),"Matches","Review Req")`

**This is being run in column B**

The first one (Step 1) is to substitute/replace specific text to standardize the values in preparation for the second formula (Step 2).

[image]

I'm hoping to see if I can combine BOTH formulas into 1 step

Comment: Replace `C136` in step 2 with `SUBSTITUTE(J136,"SE Ext '22","OE 23")`?

Comment: So I tried replacing C136 AND K136 separately but I'm still not getting any matches?

Comment: as mentioned above by @BigBen Sir, i have tried and tested it returns matches for me. `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(K136,SUBSTITUTE(J136,"SE Ext '22",K136))),"Matches","Review Req")`